# program not updating database

Tags: c#, sql

Im trying to create a form that allows users to edit a value in the database. My code below runs without error however

This is the calling method

```
private void BTNSavePool_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RWCStatTracker.Database.CLSDB.EditPool(TXTEditPool.Text, CMBBXSearchPool.SelectedItem.ToString());
        CMBBXSearchPool.Text = "Please select a Pool....";

        MessageBox.Show("Pool edited", "Alert");
        this.FRMEditPool_Load(this, null);
        PNLEditPoolSearch.Show();
    }
```

This is the code in my database connection class

```
public static void EditPool(String OldName, String NewName)
    {
        string UPDTStmt = "UPDATE TBL_Pool SET Name = @NewName WHERE Name = @OldName";
        SqlConnection conn = GetConnection();
        SqlCommand UPDTCmd = new SqlCommand(UPDTStmt, conn);
        UPDTCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewName", NewName);
        UPDTCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OldName", OldName);

        try { conn.Open(); UPDTCmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); }
        catch (SqlException ex) { throw ex; }
        finally { conn.Close(); }
    }
```

Any ideas why it's not updating?

Comment: any errors? any errors on db side? have you checked the data?

Comment: Wrap your `SqlConnection`in a `using` block, rather than a `try-finally`, it's a bit neater.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the WHERE clause isn't selecting any records.

It may have spaces:  `"Smith    "` will not match `"Smith"` or it may be case sensitive:  `"Smith"` will not match `"smith"`.

Check the data to see if it has spaces and string trim your parameters.

Answer (score -1):

I've just figured out the issue with it, the arguments are in the wrong order

This

```
public static void EditPool(String OldName, String NewName)
```

Should be

```
public static void EditPool(String NewName, String OldName)
```

Comment: Since you found your logical error and it is not very relevant to the question you may want to delete the question completely.